# iTunes Connect API

Tags: objective-c, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Does iTunes Connect has an API? How do some applications download financial and sale reports to computer? Are there some C/Objective-C API wrappers?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

### Update 11/02/2018

On November/18, Apple finally released the [**Appstore Connect REST API**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/). Referencing the Apple description:

> **TestFlight**. Manage beta builds of your app, testers, and groups.
>
> **Users and Access**. Send invitations for users to join your team. Adjust their level of access or remove users.
>
> **Reporting**. Download sales and financial reports.

### Update 10/03/2018

Good news on this one: on 2018 WWDC, Apple announced the **Appstore Connect API** - where you'll be able to access almost everything related to your Appstore Connect management. You can see two related talks [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/303/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/301/).

The only *curious* thing is that its release date was supposed to be **late this summer** - so it's probably delayed. Nonetheless we should be able to see a release **soon**.

### Update 8/18/2016

Official Reporter tool from Apple

https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/

---

iTunes finally released an auto download tool as noted in the PDF

http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

Here is the class file

http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/Autoingestion.class.zip

Comment: This is the most modern answer but unfortunately it is buried down here.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, it isn't that the API Apple uses in the Autoingestion.class is hard to understand.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work to download financial reports, or am I mistaken?

Comment: No... it does *not* download financial reports.  Which are far more useful for currency conversions... and I also need!

Comment: An objc variant: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTITCReportDownloader/

Comment: How can i parse downloaded file ?

Comment: This link is no longer valid. Got an alternative?

Answer (score 23):

There's no API for iTunes connect, the only way you can access the information is through the web or with a program that scrapes the web pages. If you want to create something in Objective-C, download AppSales from github, it's an iPhone app which downloads financial reports from ITC (or maybe itts). You can download it and install it on your iPhone if you have an Apple developer account. You can look through their code and see how they scrape the daily and weekly reports (hint: it's ugly).

http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile

Note that if you try to create an iPhone app to do this, Apple will reject it. It breaks the rule about "No public API". Other people have tried this and been rejected.

If you're just looking for software to do this on your computer, I'd highly recommend AppViz

http://www.ideaswarm.com/products/appviz/

Here's a nice post which compares these and more apps:

http://www.markj.net/sales-stats-tools-for-iphone-apps/

Comment: We have been using all of the above but were not quite happy with the results. Especially that we have apps in Apple App Store and Google Play, etc we switched to using [Distimo](http://www.distimo.com/). It is free in terms of money but you pay by providing them with free app store data obviously.

Comment: We (appFigures) have a pretty strict privacy policy. If that's important to you give us a try ;)

Comment: Also, I think Apple is against 'scraping' of iTunes websites, at least, but if you only use this functionality for development, it should be OK...

Answer (score 15):

For everything non-sales related, you might want to check out the unoffical documentation of the iTunes Connect JSON API: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

Update: There is now a Ruby implementation of both the iTunes Connect API and the Apple Developer API available: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship

Comment: Yes, that's brilliant and more relevant for today. Thanks for link! Switched connect answer.

Comment: Just trialling this. Why 'non sales related'? Would say, getting download stats (units) on a free app be related to sales? (Which is what I'm looking at polling daily programmatically).

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as correct.  `spaceship`, as great a tool as it is, is not capable of downloading "financial and sale reports" as requested, unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 8):

Following up on gavi's answer: if you download & decompile the Autoingestion class you can see the API that Apple use for sales downloads.

It consists of a POST to https://reportingitc.apple.com/autoingestion.tft with the form values: USERNAME, PASSWORD, VNDNUMBER, TYPEOFREPORT, DATETYPE, REPORTTYPE, REPORTDATE. Refer to the [PDF](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf) for details of the parameters

The response will contain the header 'ERRORMSG' if there's an error, and the header 'filename' if there's a body (presumably Apple developers don't know about Content-Disposition or 4xx/5xx status codes). The body of the response contains the file data.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small project that may be helpful to you in automating the download of piano reports from iTunes Connect.  It's a python script to automate the login / download of daily sales files and I use it daily in conjunction with some other scripts to parse that data.  Hook it up to a cron job with some error checking (the reports never seem to be generated at the same time) and you'll be good to go.

http://code.google.com/p/appdailysales/

Comment: This is the only recent one that I could find that would work for grabbing the actual data so I could do with it what I wanted, and yet it still needed some modifications because of recent Apple changes.

Answer (score 1):

No, no formal API (or if there is one, it's well hidden even from iPhone developer users of iTunes connect). However, the sales & financial reports are downloadable as tab delimited plaintext (gzip compressed), though to make the request you'll have to login (which is cookie based). One could probably wrap this process up with a little bit of screen scraping, and thus get access to the TSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.itunesapis.com. This is the missing iTunes and iTunes Connect API.

Comment: Do you think service is safe? I mean some of their parameters requier email, password, and App ID. That's a whole lot of information that Im not willing to share, especially over the wire.

Comment: I would never give the needed Apple ID information to such a 3rd party site. Even if they promise not to abuse the data they have access to, you can't be sure their servers are always safe. Also, it might be a violation of the App Store contracts to reveal password data to such 3rd parties.

Comment: At this time the link redirects to a page generated by a domain parking service.

Comment: That link looks malicious to me!

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug for my own perl5 module...

http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::iTunesConnect

Although, given yesterday's [announcement](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/06/10/apple_creates_dev_app_to_monitor_app_store_sales.html) of an official Apple app, there might be an API in the works.

Answer (score 1):

To can use the AutoIngestion Tool the vendorId is needed. 
To find it, with the last update on [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com), in the Sales and Trends section, pressing on the top 
right menu that shows "Top Content" can access to the [Reports entry (direct link).](https://reportingitc2.apple.com/reports.html)

There you can see the "Vendor" selector, pressing on it you can see the Details of the vendor with the following format:

```
VendorName - VendorId
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular one on GitHub is [spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/spaceship)

It is a Ruby library. You can `NSTask` to call ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

after looking everywhere I did not find a PHP version of the reports API so made my own.

You can check it out on https://github.com/Finnb8r/itunes-connect-sales-api-php .

I realize that this is not an Objective-C wrapper but this link comes out on top when generally looking for an API.

Answer (score 0):

There's no formal API but several open source and commercial products available that bring some/most/all info together (such as the ones mentioned in previous answers).

Another such solution is [www.appfigures.com](http://www.appfigures.com) which combines sales reports, app reviews, and hourly rank updates. Unlike the other apps appfigures can automatically import your reports and email you a nicely formatted report by email every day/week.

Comment: Have you implemented appFigures API??? If yes, please provide some code.

Comment: I'm on the appFigures team so yes :) If you contact us directly we'll guide you through and can also help with code samples. Or, there are a few client libs on github other developers have posted.

Comment: So, Please provide some Sample code. because we have no idea about how to integrate appFigure API.

Answer (score 0):

There is ITunes Store Search API:

- http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---search-api.html

It is part of Apple affiliate program.

Hope this will help you.