# How should I get App Store app comment information in iOS?

Tags: ios, comments, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iTunes Connect API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619172/itunes-connect-api)

I want to get my App Store app comment or star level information in iOS.

Does Apple provide an API to get these?