# Cannot download iTunes Connect Weekly Opt-In Report from autoingest using c# (The magic number in GZip header is not correct error)

Tags: c#, app-store-connect

We are successfully getting many of the reports from the iTunes autoingest endpoint:
**https://reportingitc.apple.com/autoingestion.tft**

However some of the reports, rather than returning the data directly in the body return a ZIP file and whenever we try to read the response we get:

**The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.**

The response headers look something like the following, indicating the zip file:

{ 
Content-Encoding: 
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=O_S_W_XXXXXXXX_20120805.zip 
filename: O_S_W_XXXXXXXX_20120805.zip 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Content-Type: application/a-gzip 
Date: Wed, 29 Aug 2012 08:54:35 GMT 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/ 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
}

But I do not really see how to access this attachment and I think the error might be something to do with the fact that I am trying to ready both the attachment and other parts of the response in one operation whereas only part of the response is actually zipped.

The code looks something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest w = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
w.Method = "POST";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

w.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

using (Stream dataStream = w.GetRequestStream())
{

dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

dataStream.Close();

using (WebResponse resp = w.GetResponse())
{

    using (System.IO.Compression.GZipStream s = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(resp.GetResponseStream(), System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
    // Just trying to read one byte causes the error.
    s.ReadByte();
    }

}
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the http body, isn't the file base64 encoded? If yes, decode the base64 first to a byte stream and then dedcompress.

Comment: Hi Rene - I can't figure out how to even get the body - whenever I try to read it I get an error. Do you have any suggested code I could try with the resp object?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619172/itunes-connect-api).

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to intercept the bytes on the wire (see the Inspectors tab).

As it turns out from the API: the stream is not GZipped but Zipped.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836736/unzip-files-programmatically-in-net) for a library to unzip a stream in c#

At the start of your app add to [overcome http 100 responses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue.aspx):

> ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

Using that you'll implement the unzipping as follows, just after you obtaind the WebResponse:

```
using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(resp.GetResponseStream()) {

    ZipEntry theEntry;
    while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null) {

        Console.WriteLine(theEntry.Name);

        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(theEntry.Name);
        string fileName      = Path.GetFileName(theEntry.Name);

        // create directory
        if ( directoryName.Length > 0 ) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
        }

        if (fileName != String.Empty) {
            using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(theEntry.Name)) {

                int size = 2048;
                byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                while (true) {
                    size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (size > 0) {
                        streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - still no luck though - when I use code above I get this error on the s.GetNextEntry()call:
**This operation is not supported.**<br /><br />

Also, when I try to decode the response in Fiddler I get this error:<br />

**
---------------------------
utilDecodeResponse failed for Session #5
---------------------------
The HTTP response body was malformed.<br />
<br />
HTTP Error: The chunked content is corrupt. Cannot find Chunk-Length in expected location. Offset: 0<br />
<br />
Type: System.IO.InvalidDataException
**

Comment: Sorry - I can't see how I can format the above and after 5 minutes of trying it's locked me out!

Comment: do this: start fiddler, use the java class as indicated in the answer of the question I referred to, to obtain a valid result, let fiddler mock that result, adapt your .net code until success.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out!

I needed to set:

```
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None;
```

Previously I had it set to try to:

```
w.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

And .NET was trying and failing to unzip the response before I even had a chance to read it.

I can now read the byte array and decrypt the file after it has been saved to disk.