# Is there any way to track the mp3 download from iTunes within the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Are there any IOS Library or framework available which can help me in downloading the MP3's from iTunes store and also I can track the download.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but here is an SO question about an iTunes Connect API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619172/itunes-connect-api

Comment: iTunes connect has nothing to do with iTunes and music for customers.  Its what publishers use to post and submit content to iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

NO. On iOS we create sandboxed apps that can't access the iTunes library on the phone.  There is no api for that and no way to do what you're looking to do without jailbreaking.