# Full iTunes Connect API

Tags: ios, api, app-store, app-store-connect

There were some questions about downloading sale reports from iTunes Connect in the past(e.g. [iTunes Connect API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619172/itunes-connect-api)), but is there a way to get the Apps information without creating something like a bot clicking through the menus(so getting information about reviews, review status, new (unreleased) versions, etc.)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: ITC app is doing that, use it or search how they did it https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect-mobile/id376771144

Comment: Well, iTC is an Apple app, they logically can do that using a private API, but is there some documentation? I didn't find one.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iTunes Connect actually features a JSON API which you can use to change/read almost anything. I collected various API endpoints on a git repo: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use the modern **App Store Connect API** with full support for doenloading Sales and Finance reports:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/sales_and_finance_reports