# How to find the number of downloads for an app in the itunes store programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

NOTE: No third party websites like Appfigures etc please.

I know how to check number of download of an app like this

> Just go to iTunes Connect, and hit "Sales and Trends". It should give
>   you the information you want.

But I would like to know,
***Is there any programmatic way through which I just pass app-id of my app and get its number of download programmatically?***

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [download](http://apple.com/itunesnews/docs/Autoingestion.class.zip) Apple's *Autoingestion tools*. For more info check the official [documentation](https://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf). However, AFAIK, you cannot filter by a specific Apple-ID, you get the entire report with all your apps.

The docs go through all the details for requesting and parsing the report but a basic example to get all the daily sales since 2015-05-01 and get you started trims down to:

1. Fill username and password in the *autoingestion.properties* file
2. In your terminal run

   `$ java Autoingestion autoingestion.properties VENDOR_ID Sales Daily Summary 20150501`

The VENDOR_ID can be retrieved from the iTunesConnect under Sales & Trends > Reports (should be a 8-digit number beginning with 8).

You'll get a .tar.gz which contains a tab separated .txt with the report.

There are plenty wrappers around the autoingest tool which might come handy in your case. One in Ruby which also contains a parser is [itunes_ingestion](https://github.com/siuying/itunes-auto-ingestion)

Comment: i read you doc...seems it will work but for fixed user info added in plist.
Is any useful dock from where we can get multiple apps detail just using apple id etc ?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect doesn't have any official API, but there are few options for you. For sales info you may find useful [itcreport](https://github.com/stoprocent/node-itunesconnect) tool that mention some iTunes Connect Reporting API, but I couldn't find any info about it. It's opensource, so if that doesn't fit your needs - you can write your own implementation. For non-sales info you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29468888/1254172) SO answer helpful.