# Is there an iTunesConnect API to get the price per country for a given in app purchase ID?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I would like to know the mapping offline on the server side for reporting and data analytics.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619172/itunes-connect-api) includes a list of apis for iTunesConnects but I could not find an api for querying the price by country in fastlane or the reporting tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with this solution:

- The client side is sending the pricing and currency code (From the SKProduct object) as the user see it to the server as part of the purchase process.
- The server side save the pricing, the currency code and the receipt data in the DB. Having a table per money transaction to hole the localized price, currency code, the USD price and pointer to the receipts table.
- Upon renewals, revalidating the receipt and if there was a renewal adding another entry to the money transaction with the same amount as was in the original money transaction (based on having the same receipt).
- For cancellation, adding a money transaction entry with minus the amount in the original transaction (again, based on the receipt).

Comment: Probably makes most sense, as there is no realtime API available anyway.

Comment: Have you found a better approach in the meantime ? It's been 5 yrs since your message and I still can't find a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

The only possible way to retrieve that kind of information might be with the **iTunes Search API**: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching

**Example App: Facetune**

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=606310581&country=kr // price 4.39

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=606310581&country=us // price 3.99

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=606310581&country=id // price 59000.00

As you get the responses in JSON, you can extract the price and currency based on the store front.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good way to find the price for the application per country but not the in app purchase price.

Comment: If you specify the use case / what you actually wanna achieve we might be able to help you better :)

Comment: It is basically for reporting reasons, I would like to know each day the price that users paid for in app purchases in the app. I would like to know it real time (not delayed like in appsfigures or iTunesConnect) and in the currency that the user payed them.