# How to show iTunesconnect sales and financial report on web?

Tags: html, ios, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-reporter

I need to display sales and financial report on HTML web page, reports data should be from iTunesConnect.

Can someone please describe how can i achieve this ?

Need to get data like below iTunes image.

[image]

Comment: itunesconnect report api should work. You need to design your own html layout with data from itunesconnect . refer to solutions provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619172/itunes-connect-api

Comment: Have you tried using JAR and property files?

Comment: Okay, let me check.

Comment: @Hasya Can you please suggest me some terminal commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apple Reporter technique, that provides you data in XML and CSV format.

**You need to follow below commands.**

```
(1) Lion:Reporter bv$ java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Finance.getReport AppleID, US, Financial, 2016, 10

Successfully downloaded AppleID_0716_US.txt.gz
(2) Lion:Reporter bv$ java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Sales.getReport AppleID, US, Financial, 2016, 10

201
Invalid report type specified. Valid values include: Sales, Newsstand, Pre-order, Cloud, Event, Customer, Content, Station, Control, amEvent, amContent, amControl, amStreams, Subscription and SubscriptionEvent.
(3) Lion:Reporter bv$ java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Finance.getReport AppleID, US, Sales, 2016, 10

301
Invalid report type specified. Valid values include: Financial, Match, Radio, RadioSummary, AppleMusic, AppleMusicSummary, News, and BeatsRadio.
(4) java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Robot.XML Sales.getReport AppleID, Sales, Summary, Daily, 20162811
```

**Using** (1) Reporter.properties and (2) Reporter.jar files. Make sure to configure Reporter.properties carefully. Like below.

```
UserId= your apple account email address

Password= your apple account password

Mode=Robot.xml
```

**Refer**

https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itcbe21ac7db

Comment: please don't promote your own website in your answer.